# Как в puppeteer эмулировать движение мышкой с нажатой клавишей?

Tags: node.js, тестирование, функциональное-тестирование

Всем привет, использую puppeteer для автоматизации тестирования,
Возник вопрос, кто-нибудь знает как кликнуть на элемент мышкой (ЛКМ )
и не отпуская ЛКМ сдвинуть ее в право на 50px?
Вот как кликнуть я знаю, как передвинуть курсор я тоже знаю, а как сделать так что бы ЛКМ была нажата во время переноса мышки не пойму, кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой задачей? подскажите как это сделать?